# Sigo teniendo problemas con una aplicación que envía SMS

Tags: vb.net

Tengo aplicación para enviar SMS cada vez que alguien le registra en el sistema. este es mi código:

```
  Dim lockObject as New Object()

    SyncLock lockObject

                     TextBoxMODEM.Clear() 

                     SerialPort1.Write("AT" & vbCrLf) 

                     Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

                     SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGF=1" & vbCrLf) 

                     Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

                     SerialPort1.Write("AT+CMGS=" & Chr(34) & TelefonoTextBox.Text & Chr(34) & vbCrLf) 

                     Threading.Thread.Sleep(100)

                     SerialPort1.Write(Mensaje.ToString & Chr(26)) 

    End SyncLock
```

Mi problema es que, cuando 2 usuarios se registran de manera simultanea, a veces el sistema no envia el SMS correspondiente. Por ejemplo, de 120 usuarios que se registraron, solo 110 recibieron el sms de confirmación.

Los sms los envió desde esta aplicación, mediante un modem Huawei e3131 el cual tengo por  usb y lo configure como modem.

La pregunta es: ¿como hago para evitar que ningún mensaje se quede en cola?

De antemano agradezco su ayuda.

Comment: Edita la pregunta, reemplaza las mayúsculas por letras minúsculas. Recuerda y ten presente que mayúsculas == gritar.

Comment: Generas algún tipo de log cuando intentas enviar el SMS? Has podido ver si llega la petición para los 120 usuarios? Sabes si sale algún error en los casos que mencionas?

Comment: No tengo ningun archivo Log, un usuario me recomendo cambiar mi codigo asi:    Class A
    Sub B
        Static lockObject as New Object()
        SyncLock lockObject

Comment: seria un interesante momento para agarrar y hacer un log ;)

Comment: gbianchi no se como hacer un Log, podrias ayudarmer pór favor?